# Get Current SPSite from Sandbox Solution SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I am migrating my WebParts from Farm Solution to Sandboxed solutions in SharePoint 2010.

Before I was doing this:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url) )
{

...
..
}
```

My sandbox solutions fails when accessing SPContext.Current.

How can I obtain the current SPSite or the current URL?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use HttpContext.Current.Request.Url or [HttpRequest.Url Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is using the SPSite constructor in the Sandbox. The following should work:

```
SPSite siteCol = SPContext.Current.Site;
```

Comment: Using constructor in sandboxed solutions is allowed. [MSDN excerpt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466911.aspx): "This constructor is allowed in sandboxed solutions. in that case, the value of the requestUrl parameter must resolve to the parent site collection in which the sandboxed solution is deployed."  As gonzalog wrote, it fails on accessing SPContext.Current.

Answer (score -1):

According to MSDN, try this:

```
using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("http://" + System.Environment.MachineName + "/sites/Site_Name"))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is wrong on two fronts.  It assumes the web application is named after the machine name and two it hard codes the name of the site.